# How to count products per each category and sub-category?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, aggregate, data-analysis

According to the specified dataframe

```
category_uuid   collection_uuid product_uuid
fe4eef35-3fde-4037-a6ce-e8ebd2859cd6    0020005c-55e3-47cb-9056-ed25dd5f24f0    00a1c641-2f8f-440d-b105-d89180cac625
fe4eef35-3fde-4037-a6ce-e8ebd2859cd6    0020005c-55e3-47cb-9056-ed25dd5f24f0    021bb4b1-e21e-4ba5-8856-15198585f873
fe4eef35-3fde-4037-a6ce-e8ebd2859cd6    0020005c-55e3-47cb-9056-ed25dd5f24f0    0331a74f-1e99-418e-9abc-304d269452b2
```

I need to calculate the following aggregated values:

```
category_uuid   collections_count   products_count
fe4eef35-3fde-4037-a6ce-e8ebd2859cd6    124 1563
...
```

i.e. to aggregate the total number of products and collections for each category.

I've tried to do the following:

```
df_products_small.groupby(['category_uuid']).agg({'collection_uuid': ['count'], ' products_count': ['count'] })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with pivot table (considering that you want the count of UNIQUE elements):

```
import pandas as pd:

pd.pivot_table(df, index='category_uuid', values=['collections_uuid', 'products_uuid'], aggfunc=lambda x: len(x.unique()))
```

Comment: Thanks! Your solution works well in my case.